# If $f\in L^1(\mathbb{T})$ is such that $\forall n<0, \hat{f}(n)=0$, does the Fourier series of $f$ converges in $L^1(\mathbb{T})$ norm to $f$?

Tags: fourier-series, harmonic-analysis

Let $\mathbb{T}$ be the 1-torus. Using the uniform boundedness principle, from the fact that $L^1(\mathbb{T})$ is a homogeneous Banach space and from
$$\|D_N*\|_{1\rightarrow1}\ge\|D_N*F_n\|_{1}\rightarrow\|D_N\|_1, n\rightarrow\infty,$$
(where $D_N$ is the Dirichlet kernel and $F_n$ is the Fejer kernel), it follows that there exists $f\in L^1(\mathbb{T})$ such that the (symmetric) Fourier series of $f$ doesn't converge to $f$ in the $L^1(\mathbb{T})$ norm (see e.g. Katznelson - An introduction to harmonic analysis). What if we add the condition that all the Fourier coefficients of negative indexes are null? Since the space $$B:=\{f\in L^1(\mathbb{T})\ |\ \forall n<0, \hat{f}(n)=0 \}$$ is still a homogeneous Banach space but $F_n \notin B$, the previous argument doesn't apply, so I'm wondering if it is true or not that there exists a $f\in B$ such that the Fourier series of $f$ doesn't converge to $f$ in $B$-norm (i.e. in $L^1(\mathbb{T})$ norm). Any suggestions?

Comment: The space $B$ is the holomorphic Hardy space $H^1$. If the $L^1$ convergence was true for it, it would also be true for real Hardy space $H_R^1$, and then I guess papers like [this one](http://matwbn.icm.edu.pl/ksiazki/sm/sm125/sm12524.pdf) would not be written. So it seems the answer is no, but I don't want to dig into the references there to find out what the story is.

Comment: Maybe something like $f(\theta) = (1-e^{i\theta})^{-1/2}$.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The article "Kehe Zhu - Duality of Bloch spaces and norm convergence of Taylor series" answers negatively to this question.